# How to run Gazebo 1.9 headless

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For a series of unattended simulations, we'd like to utilize a bunch of VMs on a server. For this, we'd like to run a Gazebo simulation server in headless mode (since a] the server has no graphics card and b] Gazebo *does **not** like* VirtualBox's OpenGL capabilities).

I've found a few mentions of using the commandline argument `-r` to run in headless (no OGRE/OpenGL) mode, but this seems to have changed in recent Gazebo. In the `--help` screen of Gazebo 1.9.5, the `-r` option is listed as "record", and no mention is made of a headless mode.

So my question is, how do I run a Gazebo 1.9 server in headless mode?

PS: If this is not available in the standard binary releases (we're using the DEB packages at the moment), I could also recompile Gazebo. I just need to find out how to use a Gazebo 1.9 with a ROS-fuerte.... (*but that's not part of this question*)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4208/how-to-run-gazebo-1.9-headless/) by [Nevik](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/329/nevik/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Yes, if your robot model has a camera then gzserver will try to create a camera. You are right, the behavior of gzserver should be: "Output a warning about no opengl support, and then continue." This sounds like a bug.

I've created and [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/814/cameras-are-not-disabled-when-running) for this. Could you add your robot model file to that issue?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1